# strftime() : bool(false) not showing nothing

Tags: php, strftime

I want to display on my page the current date in this format: 22/02/2013 - 12:00 (day/month/year - hour)

I use `strftime("%d/%b/%G - %R", time())` but shows nothing on the page. If  I do

```
echo var_dump(strftime("%d/%b/%G - %R", time()))
```

it shows bool(false). Any idea what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows [doesn't support `%G` or `%R`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx), you should use `%Y` and `%H:%M` respectively.

```
strftime("%d/%b/%Y - %H:%M")
```

Comment: Is it also possible to set the time according to the localtime too?? how can i do this??

Comment: What do you mean? Whose local time?

Comment: @Lykos You mean [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)?

Comment: I need some more help please . I have the strftime is inside a <p id="date"> and wht i'd like to do is to add some ajax. How can I apply the strftime function inside my jquery .load() function???

<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#dateTime').load(???);
 
});
</script>

Comment: @Lyk that should be another question then.

Comment: Windows doesn't support %e either, use %d instead.

Comment: @user2019515 The question wasn't so much about what other things Windows doesn't support :)

Comment: @Jack The problem was Windows not supporting format date strings, noting which strings aren't supported seems appropriate.

Comment: @user2019515 Except that the use of `%e` is clearly mentioned in the manual for strftime() whereas `%G` and `%R` are somewhat harder to find.

Answer (score 7):

From the [`strftime()` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php):

> As the output is dependent upon the underlying C library, some conversion specifiers are not supported. On Windows, supplying unknown conversion specifiers will result in 5 **E_WARNING** messages and return **FALSE**. On other operating systems you may not get any **E_WARNING** messages and the output may contain the conversion specifiers unconverted.

So, you are probably using unsupported format parameters.

Note: by default `time()` is used for a timestamp, so you can use `strftime()` with it if you require this defaul tiemstamp.

Comment: @Jack It depends on the underlying C library, which is different for each OS. This information is not supplied, so I cannot go into more details...

Comment: " Windows only:

The %e modifier is not supported in the Windows implementation of this function. To achieve this value, the %#d modifier can be used instead. The example below illustrates how to write a cross platform compatible function.

The %z and %Z modifiers both return the time zone name instead of the offset or abbreviation. "

I don't get it. Only the parameters that says here are not supported in Windows or not???

Comment: not only those, on the same man page is written "This means that %e, %T, %R and, %D (and possibly others) - as well as dates prior to Jan 1, 1970 - will not work on Windows, some Linux distributions, and a few other operating systems"

Comment: Yes, but it is also stated that it depends on the underlying C library... You best shot is to try and find out which modifier is not working by removing one at the time until your code works...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo date('d/m/Y - H:s');
```

If you need to, you can set the timezone like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Comment: `date()` is not locale sensitive.

Comment: @OgunAcik Please do not modify another users post by *adding additional details*, instead use a comment to point these additional details, so the OP can determine whether or not to update his post (if he agrees)

Comment: I agree and have added the changes myself, thanks @OgunAcik for the suggestion, best to suggest in comments first as Veger says though! :)